# Circle within a circle. Is it an open set?

Tags: general-topology

> Consider an open set $M$ defined by an open circle with radius $R=2$ minus the unit circle.
>
> Is $M$ open? What are the interior points of $M$? Is $\mathbb{C} \backslash M$ connected?

Alright, so my first step was to write down what I have, which is:

$M=\{z:|z|<2\}\ \backslash \{z:|z|<1\}$, right?

Intuitively I can see that this set is open, but I don't know how to write down a rigorous proof for that. And if it's an open set isn't it already connected?

I would appreciate any help with that.

Comment: Hi, it would be helpful if you could specify what definition of an open set you are using. Best

Comment: I think it should be "disk", not "circle" the right word, at least according with M being as you wrote. In that case it is not open (with the usual metric), since any point $z$,  with $|z|<1$ is in your set $M$ but there is no open ball centered in $z$ contained in $M$

Comment: It's not clear what $M$ even is. Do you mean the open disk of radius 2, minus the unit circle? That is an open set in $\mathbb{C}$. The confusion is that you seem to be mixing up "disk" with "circle," which mean two different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, according to your definitions, we have

outer circle $U:=\lbrace z\in\mathbb{C}: |z|<2\rbrace$, and

inner unit circle $V:=\lbrace z\in\mathbb{C}: |z|<1\rbrace$.

Then $M:=U-V$ is not open. Why? Note that the set $L:=\lbrace z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|=1\rbrace$ is a subset of $M$. And for each $z\in L$, every open ball around $z$ is not contained in $M$. Since every open set in $\mathbb{C}$ must contain an open ball around each point of its, we conclude that $M$ is not open.

Edited for consistent notations.